# Anakin killing the Jedi younglings vs. using them - why?

Tags: star-wars

In Episode Three, the very infamous scene where Anakin walks into the younglings training room, Anakin decides to kill them all.

Why didn't he trick/force them into coming with him so he or the Emperor could train them as Sith Troopers!

Answer (score 8):

Quite simply, because Darth Sidious told him to - partially to prevent future problems/opposition, and as a means to turn Vader more and more to the Dark Side.

Vader listens to him because he is told that by building his Dark Side powers, he will be strong enough to save Padme.

From [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html):

> PALPATINE: **Every single Jedi, including your friend Obi-Wan Kenobi, is now an enemy of the Republic.** You understand that, don't you?
>
> ANAKIN: I understand, Master.
>
> PALPATINE: We must move quickly. The Jedi are relentless; **if they are not all destroyed, it will be civil war without end.** First, I want you to go to the Jedi Temple. We will catch them off balance. Do what must be done, Lord Vader. Do not hesitate. Show no mercy. **Only then will you be strong enough with the dark side to save Padme.**

Answer (score 1):

By Sith rule of two there should be one 2 Siths, the Master and the disciple

[rule of two from wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_of_Two)

Comment: But not all Dark Jedi are Sith.  It's totally cool for a Sith to have one or more Dark Jedi work for them.  'Sith' refers to people trained in a certain style of Force use, following a particular set of teachings, which leads them to learn specific applications of powers.

Comment: According to Palpatine's new Rule of One (to be implemented after the Jedi are defeated), the Sith will consist of him as the master and an army of dark side-using minions at his command, but never fully a Sith. That is how, from the asker's perspective, the younglings could have been converted by Anakin - not Sith troopers like he said, but simply Dark Jedi. This all may be Legends now, but the principles still apply to the new canon. There are plenty of Inquisitors and such in the Empire, and Palpatine has experimented with turning babies before, so younglings aren't implausible.

Answer (score 0):

Anakin is now Darth Vader and is going to become one of the strongest Sith Lords, so him killing all of them is eliminating any possible challenge for him.

Comment: Can you provide any sources to support your answer?